# Python 3 Windows install giving package error ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have recently started using Python and have installed version 3.7.3 on my Windows 10 machine running as administrator. I then ran the following command in a command prompt to install the xmpppy package

```
python -m pip install xmpppy
```

Next I created the following base.py file that uses the aforementioned xmpppy package

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import xmpp

user="user"
password="pword"
server="server"

jid = xmpp.JID(user) 
connection = xmpp.Client(server,debug=[]) 
connection.connect() 
result = connection.auth(jid.getNode(), password,"LFY-client") 

connection.sendInitPresence() 

while connection.Process(1): 
pass
```

Now when I run the command

```
python base.py
```

in the folder that the base.py file exists I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "base.py", line 3, in <module>
  import xmpp
 File "C:\Users\AGO109\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xmpp\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import simplexml,protocol,debug,auth,transports,roster,dispatcher,features,browser,filetransfer,commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplexml'
```

In the folder C:\Users\AGO109\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xmpp simplexml.py, protocol.py etc. all exist and the windows system variables contain the paths for python and packages, so what's the problem?

Comment: Why are you using the Linux hashbang: `#!/usr/bin/env python` if you are on Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue.

Try installing each of the packages using command like `pip install simplexml` and then run your code. Mine is stuck at installing `transports`.

Alternately,you may try switching to using `sleekxmpp` that comes bundled with your python installation. As `sleekxmpp` has latest version published in 2017 compared to that of 2006 for `xmpppy`, i'm planning to stick with using `sleekxmpp` library. If you update your code to use  `sleekxmpp` as per the boilerplate code at https://pypi.org/project/sleekxmpp/, XMPP connections work.